# Number of bijective function

Tags: functions

How many bijective function can be formed from a set to itself if it contains 'n' number of elements?

I just dont know the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's map $\{1, 2, \dots n\}$ to itself.

Step 1: Map element 1 somewhere. How many ways can this be done?

Step 2: Map element 2 somewhere. How many ways can this be done? (Notice you can't repeat your choice from Step 1, as the function would no longer be injective.)

...

Step n: Map element $n$ somewhere. How many ways can this be done?

The Fundamental Theorem of Counting states that the total number of ways to complete this task will be the product of the number of ways to do each step. What is this total value?

Answer (score 1):

This is where we think about what a bijective function from a set onto itself really is. There are many interpretations, but in this case, I like to think of each such function as a specific shuffle. Take $n$ elements, and $n$ "seats", where the seats are numbered in ascending order. Shuffle the elements and put them in the seats. Each different way of doing this is a new bijection. How many ways are there? I am sure you've answered questions like this before.